# Recommendations for a binary expression tree library for boolean expressions in Java

Tags: java, expression-trees, boolean-expression, soot

I'm doing some very simple program analyses/transformations in Java using [Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/), and I find myself needing to do some simple combinations of boolean expressions.  So for example, during my analysis, I'll have an expression like `(a < 25) && (b >= 10)` and I want to join that expression with `(a >=-10)` via an OR operator to get a full expression like `(a >=-10) || (a < 25) && (b >= 10)`.  Basically, just combining two boolean expression trees into one expression.  I might further desire to automatically convert the expression tree into an equivalent conjunctive normal form version of the tree.

Another requirement I have is the ability to simplify the expression (via custom code, if needed) when we have expressions that can be trivially eliminated.  For example `(a < 20) || (a >= 20)` reduces to `TRUE`, since `(a < 20) = (!(a >= 20))`, so we can eliminate some terms as we go.

I know it's a classic introductory problem to code up a boolean expression tree, and I'm pretty sure I've implemented it before (once, long ago, for a data structures class :) )   I know I could do it again, if needed... But given that this is likely something that's been handled before, I wonder if there are any recommendations on a library I should look into to tackle the above.  I hate to re-invent the wheel when there's probably a perfectly good one out there already.

So to summarize I'm looking for a Java libary that has:

- Boolean expression trees
- Combination of expressions
- Simplification of terms (this is pretty specific, so it's "nice to have")
- Conversion to CNF

Any recommendations?

(NOTE: I won't be *evaluating* these trees, so each of the nodes will be unresolved predicates like `variable != 20` or `foo >= 50`, so evaluation isn't a requirement, but it doesn't hurt if it's part of the library, either.)

Comment: This isn't a good fit for a SO question. Please see: [What Stack Overflow is Not: Stack Overflow doesn't provide product or service recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/185290)

Comment: Whoops.  I've just seen so many highly rated recommendation questions and found so much help from such SO questions, I inferred it must be okay.  My bad!

Comment: You've obviously put some effort into the question, so maybe the SO gods will smile upon you ...